# Por que los archivos de office no los puedo codificar/encriptar correctamente en c#?

Tags: c#, base64, codificación, ms-word

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
   public string cifrar(String cadena)
        {
            

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

             CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,Cifrador.CreateEncryptor(key,iv),(CryptoStreamMode.Write));


            byte[] cadenaBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cadena);

             cryptoStream.Write(cadenaBytes, 0, cadenaBytes.Length);

            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            byte[] mensaje_cifrado = memoryStream.ToArray();

            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();

            return Convert.ToBase64String(mensaje_cifrado);
        }
```

El codigo anterior codifica texto,tengo aparte otra funcion que lo que hace es leer un archivo linea por linea y cambia el texto plano por el codificado ayudandome de la funcion antes descrita.

Ya realize varias pruebas en diversos textos y funciona correctamente, el problema es cuando intento codificar un archivo de word y lo decodifica, no lo decodifica correctamente.

Pienso que es por que hay algunos caracteres que usa word que no estoy contemplando,por lo que me gustaria saber cual es la estructura del archivo de word para saber como tratarla o si saben que caracteres meten que no los pueda tratar con mi funcion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un archivo de Word no es texto plano, no puedes leer su contenido de la misma forma que haces con un txt (o cualquier otro archivo que puedes ver desde el bloc de notas).

.doc es un archivo binario y .docx es un zip que contiene xmls y varios otros tipos de archivos dentro.

Podrías encriptarlo como archivo completo, no linea por linea.
Tal ves esto te sirva:

[Tutorial: Crear una aplicación criptográfica](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/security/walkthrough-creating-a-cryptographic-application)

[Encriptar / desencriptar archivos en C#](http://jbautistam.com/Articulos/Seguridad/Encriptar-archivos.htm)

Comment: lo que busco no es encriptarlo de una sola vez , si no por segmentos, pero muchas gracias , como bien comentaste en vez de leerlo por llinea, lo lei por bytes, eso solvento mi problema muchas gracias